# Adding data to an array list

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm working on an Android project and I'm trying to make use of an `ArrayList` which is of type `MyClass`. I am trying to store data in the `ArrayList` to each of the variables within `MyClass`. Below is the code I am using.

Below is the Class with the variables that will be used.

```
class SearchData
{
    public int id;
    public String category;
    public String company;
    public String loginAction;
    public String username;
    public String password;
    public String type;
    public String appName;
}
```

Below is how I am initialising the `ArrayList`

```
ArrayList<SearchData> passwords = new ArrayList<SearchData>();
```

And below is how I am trying to add new data to the `ArrayList`

```
passwords.add(new SearchData()
{

});
```

I can't figure out how to then set the variables from within the class with the data that I need them to be set to. In C#, which I know more about than Java, I can do the following:

```
passwords.add(new SearchData()
{
    id = 0,
    category = "hello"                      
});
```

However, I'm not seeing any of the variables that are within the class being shown in the Intellisense help.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you asking how to statically initialise passwords?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an object and set all the attributes first, and then add it to the `List`: -

```
SearchData searchData = new SearchData();
searchData.setId(1);
searchData.setCategory(category);
...

passwords.add(searchData);
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a constructor for your class.

```
class SearchData
{
    public int id;
    public String category;
    public String company;
    public String loginAction;
    public String username;
    public String password;
    public String type;
    public String appName;

   SearchData(int id, String category, String company......){

         this.id = id;
         this.category = category;
         this.company = company;
         ...
   }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
passwords.add(new SearchData(0,"Category1", "Company1"......));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Create an object and store reference to it:**

```
SeachData searchData = new SearchData();
```

**Set the properties you want to set:**

```
searchData.setId(123);
```

...so on

`searchData.` **Ctrl+Space** should show the intellisense now..

**Adding the search reference to the list:**

```
list.add(searchData);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SearchData sd = new SearchData();
sd.id = 0;
sd.category = "hello";
passwords.add(sd);
```