# java.lang.NullPointerException while trying to add data to object of class in Android

Tags: java, android

I am facing a silly problem. I am simply trying to add data to an object of my class, and not succeeding.

I am fetching data via an Asynchronous task inside my fragment and want to use the resulting JSON to fill my ListView. I am using an ArrayAdapter and have created a class for this purpose.

I have parsed the JSON String and now I am trying to add the data retrieved from the API to the object of my class, but it gives me 'java.lang.NullPointerException'.

I guess I am not being able to add data to the object of my class. But I fail to understand the reason, I am more used to cding in C#, but JAVA being Object_Oriented, it should be the same, right? The code being used is as below...

```
    JSONArray jsonArrayPendingBills = new JSONArray();
    jsonArrayPendingBills = jsonObjectPendingBills.getJSONArray(TAG_RESPONSE_MESSAGE);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayPendingBills = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    ArrayList<PendingBills> arrayClassPendingBills = new ArrayList<PendingBills>();

    for(int i = 0;i < jsonArrayPendingBills.length(); i++){
        JSONObject jsonObjectPendingBill = jsonArrayPendingBills.getJSONObject(i);

        String strDate = jsonObjectPendingBill.getString(TAG_PENDING_BILLS_DATE);
        String strTxCode = jsonObjectPendingBill.getString(TAG_PENDING_BILLS_TX_CODE);
        String strFromAccount = jsonObjectPendingBill.getString(TAG_PENDING_BILLS_FROM_ACCOUNT);
        String strAmount = jsonObjectPendingBill.getString(TAG_PENDING_BILLS_AMOUNT);
        String strDetails = jsonObjectPendingBill.getString(TAG_PENDING_BILLS_DETAILS);
        String strBillCode = jsonObjectPendingBill.getString(TAG_PENDING_BILLS_BILL_CODE);

        PendingBills objPendingBills = new PendingBills();
        objPendingBills.setBillAmount(strAmount);
        objPendingBills.setBillDate(strDate);
        objPendingBills.setBillName(strFromAccount);
        //arrayClassPendingBills.add(new PendingBills(strAmount, strDate, strFromAccount));
        arrayClassPendingBills.add(objPendingBills);
    }

    PendingBillsAdapter pendingBillsAdapter = new PendingBillsAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.pending_bills_list_view_row, arrayClassPendingBills);
    listViewPendingBills.setAdapter(pendingBillsAdapter);

    progressDialogPendingBills.dismiss();
}
catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.i("Error", "Error", e);
}
```

This is the code for my class:

```
public class PendingBills {

    // Declaring the strings for the class
    public String BillAmount;
    public String BillDate;
    public String BillName;

    // Writing down the constructor for this class  
    public PendingBills(String BillAmount, String BillDate, String BillName){
        this.BillAmount = BillAmount;
        this.BillDate = BillDate;
        this.BillName = BillName;
    }

    public PendingBills(){

    }

    // Getter for BillAmount
    public String getBillAmount(){
        return BillAmount;
    }

    // Setter for BillAmount
    public void setBillAmount(String BillAmount){
        this.BillAmount = BillAmount;
    }

    public String getBillDate(){
        return BillDate;
    }

    public void setBillDate(String BillDate){
        this.BillDate = BillDate;
    }

    public String getBillName(){
        return BillName;
    }

    public void setBillName(String BillName){
        this.BillName = BillName;
    }

}
```

I think I am missing something. I am not sure what? I have looked up a few questions on StackOverflow relating to this. I found many of them, but the solutions did not work for me.

[Adding data to an array list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670403/adding-data-to-an-array-list)

[How to properly add data to ArrayList - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18388629/how-to-properly-add-data-to-arraylist-android)

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Here is the LogCat....

```
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at com.zipcash.zipcashbetaversion.PendingBillsAdapter.getView(PendingBillsAdapter.java:43)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1246)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1158)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:681)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:681)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1029)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:681)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-02 07:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(4648):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post your logcat stack trace.

Comment: Which code gives NPE?

Comment: Check these images: [Debugging](http://i.imgur.com/HtpLIVw.png) and [Log_Cat](http://i.imgur.com/4JYg66b.png)

Comment: @Aamirkhan, I have posted my LogCat.

Comment: @Bot what is the line number **43** in `PendingBillsAdapter.java`

Comment: @Tamilan am inflating my layout in that line: LayoutInflater inflator = activity.getLayoutInflater();

Comment: @Bot inflat your layout like this `LayoutInflater  inflater =     (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
` and run it. and also post your `PendingBillsAdapter.java`.

Comment: @Tamilan, it gives me a syntax error: 'The method getSystemService(String) is undefined for the type PendingBillsAdapter'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

inflate your layout like below codes. `context.getSystemService` or `this`

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
```

or

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
```

Answer (score 0):

k dude just maintain that arrayPendingBills to static or use datacontroller class like singleton class for short u just maintain arrayPendingBills  to static then run it will be fine :) best of luck

Answer (score 0):

```
- add try & Catch to handle nullPointerException & any Exceptions 
- Make trace the code to find where made excption.
- add system.out.Println to print the values then they find the exception
```

> try{
>            JSONArray jsonArrayPendingBills = new JSONArray();
>           jsonArrayPendingBills = jsonObjectPendingBills.getJSONArray(TAG_RESPONSE_MESSAGE);
>           ArrayList> arrayPendingBills = new ArrayList>();
>           ArrayList arrayClassPendingBills = new ArrayList();
>
> ```
>     for(int i = 0;i < jsonArrayPendingBills.length(); i++){
>         JSONObject jsonObjectPendingBill = jsonArrayPendingBills.getJSONObject(i);
>
>         String strDate = jsonObjectPendingBill.getString(TAG_PENDING_BILLS_DATE);
>         String strTxCode = jsonObjectPendingBill.getString(TAG_PENDING_BILLS_TX_CODE);
>         String strFromAccount = jsonObjectPendingBill.getString(TAG_PENDING_BILLS_FROM_ACCOUNT);
>         String strAmount = jsonObjectPendingBill.getString(TAG_PENDING_BILLS_AMOUNT);
>         String strDetails = jsonObjectPendingBill.getString(TAG_PENDING_BILLS_DETAILS);
>         String strBillCode = jsonObjectPendingBill.getString(TAG_PENDING_BILLS_BILL_CODE);
>
>         PendingBills objPendingBills = new PendingBills();
>         objPendingBills.setBillAmount(strAmount);
>         objPendingBills.setBillDate(strDate);
>         objPendingBills.setBillName(strFromAccount);
>         //arrayClassPendingBills.add(new PendingBills(strAmount, strDate, strFromAccount));
>         arrayClassPendingBills.add(objPendingBills);
>     }
>   PendingBillsAdapter pendingBillsAdapter = new PendingBillsAdapter(getActivity(),        
> R.layout.pending_bills_list_view_row, arrayClassPendingBills);
>     listViewPendingBills.setAdapter(pendingBillsAdapter);
>
>     progressDialogPendingBills.dismiss();
> }catch ( NullPointerException e)
> {
> e.printStackTrace();
>  Log.i("Error", "Error", e);
> }
> catch (Exception e){
>     e.printStackTrace();
>     Log.i("Error", "Error", e);
> }
> ```